# Has there ever been a gender-changing Time Lord before?

Tags: doctor-who

Is 13 going to be the first time (that we know of, obviously) that a Time Lord has changed genders during a regeneration? Preferably looking for in-canon or almost-canon, so anything other than the Curse of Fatal Death.

Comment: You mean other than the Corsair, The Master, and the Timelord General?

Comment: Missy even made reference to when the Doctor was "A little girl" (although, being Missy, it might have been a joke).

Comment: And FYI, Doctor Who doesn't really *do* canon.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins well that's just not true. Canonity is definitely fluid but you can't actually tell me that anyone considers Curse of Fatal Death to be a story that happened in the world, well I would imagine most people DO consider the seasons of the show to have "actually" happened, although there are certainly contradictions like in any fictional universe of this size

Comment: There is certainly no official canon. I suppose for much of the series since the reboot they keep a continuity book (whether Time Crash qualifies for this is dubious). Peter Cushing isn't an official Doctor, despite being in two films approved by the BBC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Master (John Simm) regenerated into Missy (Michele Gomez) at some point between last appearance (Season 6?) and Season 8 of the current running Dr. Who -- to choose an obviously current/canon example.

Comment: This is an incomplete answer. The Master was not the first, nor the only one to change gender upon regeneration. The show has been spilling it out for years...the Doctor can be female. Why is everyone so surprised?

Comment: It's a yes or no question.  This is a supported "no".  How is that incomplete?  The fact that The Master/Missy wasn't the first, either, is irrelevant to the question as asked.